# When I select the Donut object thousands of giant coordinate systems show up

Tags: coordinates

I'm a Newbie in Blender. Now I'm learning Blender with the Donut Tutorial.

I met a question today about the coordinate system. When I chose an object (Donut), then came a giant coordinate system, or even thousands of coordinate systems, as I clicked Icing.

Does anyone know what is that? How can I solve it?

[image]
[image]

Comment: hello maybe in the Options panel (top right of your 3D view) you've enabled the Affect Only Origins option?

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: @moonboots Dude, thank you soooo much!! : >

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *Options* panel (top right of your 3D view) disable the *Transform Affect Only Origins* option:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!